# Websocket issue on wildfly cluster

Tags: java, websocket, cluster-computing, wildfly-8, mod-cluster

I am using richfaces a4j:push in my Spring-JSF integrated application. I am able to push messages to the browser using websocket in my non cluster environment on wildfly 8.0.0.
When I deploy the application on wildfly8.0.0 on redhat enterprise 7.0 with httpd clustering the push messages are not working.

I get the following error on cluster environment:

```
17:15:22,862 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /star/__richfaces_push: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000077: The underlying transport does not support HTTP upgrade.
```

My cluster is configured with mod_cluster, referring the [document](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/WildFly+8+Cluster+Howto)

When I look for details on error UT000077, it says ‘Apache httpd doesn't support HTTP upgrade out of box’ I understand HTTP upgrade is required for websocket communication. It is suggested to use mod_proxy_wstunnel. However the details are not available for this configuration.

Any pointers/suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of this answer AJP [which is the default one] does not support HTTP upgrade and hence not websocket.

If you switch to HTTP websocket will work.

Following changes you need to do to switch to AJP

Change

```
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

To

```
#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

[comment out proxy_ajp_module and added proxy_http_module]

In modcluster sub-system

Change

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.2">
<mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" connector="ajp">
<dynamic-load-provider>
<load-metric type="cpu"/>
</dynamic-load-provider>
</mod-cluster-config>
</subsystem>
```

To

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.2">
<mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" connector="default">
<dynamic-load-provider>
<load-metric type="cpu"/>
</dynamic-load-provider>
</mod-cluster-config>
</subsystem>
```

[“default” is the name of the http listener]

Also you need to load mod_proxy_wstunnel in your httpd

Comment: And ```EnableWsTunnel``` in mod_cluster.conf. Beware: Current [mod_cluster 1.3.1.Final](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ModclusterVersion131FinalReleased) is capable of mod_proxy_wstunnel integration, i.e. it creates connections to the least loaded/elected nodes, but there is no failover functionality. If the worker node fails, the WS connection is lost.

Comment: @MichalKarmBabacek does it mean, the configuration changes which Sam suggested plus EnableWsTunnel in mod_cluster.conf on a mod_cluster 1.3.1.Final will make the websocket working in one of the cluster node ?

Comment: @Rakesh, it will enable it for the whole cluster. Essentially, it will automatically [generate these ProxyPass directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html) for you, i.e. for all contexts on all of your worker nodes.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and bringing up this good point.

Comment: Anyone have ideia of how to enable EnableWsTunnel using Apache 2.2 and if is it possible ? I compiled mod_proxy_wstunnel for Apache 2.2 with success but I don't know if is also possible with mod_cluster

Comment: Yes!! it's possible, I build mod_cluster 1.3.3 with Apache 2.2 and mod_proxy_wstunnel too. Now I can use WebSocket with Apache 2.2.Now I have another problem to synchronize client notifications spread in the nodes. Hands on work!!

Answer (score 1):

[MODCLUSTER-438](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/MODCLUSTER-438) WebSocket support for mod_cluster

Comment: Thank you, I will keep an eye on this

Answer (score 0):

Let me give my two cents in this question to people there are using Apache 2.2.x If are you using Apache 2.2.x you need to compile the mod_proxy_wstunnel from Apache 2.4 for Apache 2.2.x This [link](https://notmyitblog.blogspot.com.br/2014/03/websockets-support-for-apache-httpd.html) have a how to do it. Following, to achieve WebSockets with mod_cluster you need also compile mod_cluster 1.3.3+ as described in this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.3.0/html_single/#native.building) and add EnableWsTunnel in your mod_cluster.conf outside your virtual host

I hope helps.